# Setting Size and Color of CalloutMarker?

Tags: plotting

Can we set the size of `CalloutMarker`? Also how to change the color of the `CalloutMarker` and `Leader` when I use `"Star"` ?

```
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotLabels -> Callout["Sin[x]", {2, Above}, CalloutMarker -> "Star"]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotLabels -> Callout["Sin[x]", {2, Above}, 
    CalloutMarker -> {"Star", 24}, 
    CalloutStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotLabels -> Callout["Sin[x]", {2, Above}, 
    CalloutMarker -> {"Star", 24}, 
    CalloutStyle -> FaceForm[Red]]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotLabels -> 
  Callout["Sin[x]", {2, Above}, 
   CalloutMarker -> {"Star", 24}, 
   CalloutStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick, FaceForm[Red]]]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotLabels -> 
  Callout["Sin[x]", {2, Above}, 
   CalloutMarker -> {"Star", 24}, 
   CalloutStyle -> Red, 
   LabelStyle -> {14, Bold, Red}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Now, I am trying to change the color of the callout label `Sin[x]`.             
                    `LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Blue}` works, but `LabelStyle -> {12, Bold,Red}`  doesn' t work.

Comment: @RF_1, `LabelStyle -> {12, Bold,Red}` works both in version 11.3 (windows) and version.12.3 (wolfram cloud).

Comment: After creating a new `.nb` file, and `Quit[]`, it works. But interestingly, I have a `.nb` file including many line codes, it still doesn't work in the `.nb` file. When I run `LabelStyle -> {12, Bold,Red}`, callout label is 12 point and `Bold`, but it is Black not Red. Besides, Green and Blue works, but orange and red doesn' t work. It's very very interesting. 12.3 (windows)